# Embedding a bokeh plot in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bokeh

I am expecting to get a simple line bokeh plot returned by Flask, but what I get when I browse to localhost:5002/simpleline is this:

('', '
')

I have two files. The Python file:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.embed import components
from flask import Flask, render_template
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/simpleline/')
def simpleLine():
    fig=figure(title="Sensor data")
    fig.line([1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8])
    div=components(fig)
    return render_template('simpleline.html',div=div)
    show(fig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=5002)
```

And the HTML template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Figure examples</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.7.1.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript"src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='bokeh'>
 {{ div|safe }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure I am missing something essential here.

After mn's answer, it was found out that `components()` produces two elements, a Javascript string, and an html div. So, I updated my scripts as follows, but this time the web page shows as blank.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.embed import components
from flask import Flask, render_template
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/simpleline/')
def simpleLine():
    fig=figure(title="Sensor data")
    fig.line([1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8])
    global script
    global div
    script,div=components(fig)
    return render_template('simpleline.html',div=div,script=script)
    output_file("simpleline.html")
    show(fig)

fig=figure(title="Sensor data")
fig.line([1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8])
script,div=components(fig)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=5002)
```

And the HTML template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Figure examples</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
  {{ script|safe }}
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='bokeh'>
   {{ div|safe }}
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried all bokeh-0.7.1.min.js, 0.9, and 0.10, but I still got the same blank page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`components()` returns `(script, div)` tuple with `<script>` that contains the data for your plot and an accompanying `<div>` tag that the plot view is loaded into:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components

```
script, div = components(fig)
return render_template('simpleline.html',div=div, script=script)
```

template

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Figure examples</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.10.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
  {{ script|safe }}
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='bokeh'>
   {{ div|safe }}
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Things make much more sense now. Thanks! However, now I am getting a blank page and I don't know why.

Comment: try with bokeh-0.10.0.min.js or 0.9.0

Comment: Still the same. I updated the question by adding the scripts I have so far if that helps.

Comment: @mn, I am bothering you with one more question. Could you please explain the difference between the external Javascript code and the one produced by components(). What do they serve for?

Comment: External code is a BokehJS library. Code produced by components() contains the data for you plot and uses BokehJS for plotting.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also use `autoload_static` instead of `components` if you want the bokeh js and css to load automatically. Also you can save the js into a filepath and use only the div in the html to access it.

Here is a sample code that I worked with:

```
from bokeh.embed import autoload_static
from bokeh.resources import CDN
.............
.............
js, div = autoload_static(bar, CDN, '/static/bokeh/plot.js')
with open('static/bokeh/plot.js', 'w') as f:
        f.write(js)
```

And then in the html file include only the div tag (includes the path of the js script).

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Figure examples</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class='bokeh'>
    {{ div|safe }}
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Sure. There can be a problem with caching (not displaying plots unless refreshing) since a new div id is generated every time. Can be managed by setting appropriate cache-control headers - expiry etc or other workarounds.